# Spring import xml from a bundle

Tags: spring

I have a java application that use spring with a spring.xml file in the web content. I have in my java class this piece of code:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("WEB-INF/spring-conf.xml");
WService ws = (WService) context.getBean("service");
```

In that spring.xml I import a xml file that lives in a library (bundle) that I've put in my project as an external library.

```
<import resource="classpath:/org/bundle/spring2.xml" />
```

and it works but in spring2.xml and in the bundle there are also:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location">
    <value>../properties/environment.properties</value>
  </property>
</bean>
<import resource="../commons/datasources.xml"></import>
<import resource="../commons/context-resources.xml"></import>
```

and I can't find these xml files because they live in the bundle, not in my webcontent.
How can I indicate in my spring-conf.xml the positions of the other xml files from the beginning?
If there are another method to do this you're welcome.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing yourself the XMLs in your `spring-conf.xml`:

```
<import resource="classpath:<PACKAGE_PATH>/datasources.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:<PACKAGE_PATH>/context-resources.xml" />
```

and replace `PACKAGE_PATH` with the correct value :-)

Comment: is it possible to import multiple  xml files in one line? if they are all under a common package, instead of writing 50 lines of import, can we use wildcards ( *resource.xml  would import Aresourse.xml, Bresourse.xml etc) ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to edit these imports to use classpath prefix?

```
<import resource="classpath:/org/commons/datasources.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:/org/commons/context-resources.xml"/>
```

This way they should be available to anyone using this library.